# JQuery - finding the correct div depending on input value

Tags: jquery, arrays, date

im stuck with a problem

im basically trying to create a function where I allocate different text (from an array) to different divs which are of the same class, these divs are differentiated by an id, here is an example of what i mean

**HTML markup**

```
<div class='actContainer'>
    <div class='msgContainer'>
       <input class='activityId' type='hidden' value='1'>
       <div class='date'> </div> 
    </div>

    <div class='msgContainer'>
       <input class='activityId' type='hidden' value='2'>
       <div class='date'> </div> 
    </div>

    <div class='msgContainer'>
       <input class='activityId' type='hidden' value='3'>
       <div class='date'> </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery code**

```
var textArr = ['time1', 'time2', 'time3'];
var id = [1, 2, 3];

$.each(textArr, function(key, value){      
   $('.actContainer').find('input#activityId').val()==id[key]
     .parent().find('div.date')
     .append("Posted message at"+textArr[key]); 
}
```

As you can see from the code im trying to place text between the div.date tag.

This currently doesn't work so I must be doing something wrong, if anyone could help that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
 $('.actContainer').find('input.activityId[value="'+id[key]+'"]')
     .siblings('.date')
     .text("Posted message at"+textArr[key]);
```

This means that you are searching for an input with the activityId class, which also has a value that is equals to id[key].
you would like to find a div near it that has a class date, and you'd like to change it's text content to "posted message ... "

Comment: Did you try this? The DIVs are not using the 'actContainer' class but 'msgContainer'

Comment: I was under the impression that he has a higher structure which he didn't share with us, which contains this entire code.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I've appended it now.

Comment: You may be right. It that's the case, then this works. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The "activityId" appears to be a class, not an ID.
Also I'd recommend putting an ID on the date div directly, or either put the ID on the parent element (the one with class msgContainer). That will make addressing the date div easier.

Comment: activityId is an ID in the sense that every message has its own unique integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple code:

```
$.each(textArr, function(key, value) {
  key = key +1
  $('input[value="'+key+'"]').siblings('.date').text("Posted message at "+value);
});
```

I've edited your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9FAhJ/1/